# Migrate Visual FoxPro project and database to PHP/Laravel web app

Tags: php, sql, laravel, visual-foxpro

Is there a way to use Visual FoxPro database to a web app (MySql database)?

Here is the situation:
There is a Visual FoxPro project with a database. I want to make a Laravel app from scratch and replicate the logic used by FoxPro, and the only thing I need is the database from FoxPro (I don`t want to loose the records).

How can I transform FoxPro database (which have .dbc or .dbf extensions I think) to sql files, so I can import tables to phpMyAdmin? Or do you have any suggestion how can I use all the records from all tables?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, this is not an answer to your question, but just for your knowledge. If you need to expose foxpro data via nodejs  (javascript) to the web (without spending a dime), then there is a way. Do watch "Nodejs for Fox Developers" on Geek Gatherings channel on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

1. In "Choose a Data Source" dialog, choose "Visual Foxpro Database (*.dbc) " or "FoxPro/dBase Free Table (*.dbf)" ;

- Click "..." to browse the Visual Foxpro Database file(.dbc) or select the folder which the Foxpro/dBase free tables locating.
- Click "Next" to goto the next step.
- Visual Foxpro(*.dbc)
- Visual Foxpro Database (*.dbc)
- Foxpro Free Table
- Foxpro Free Table(*.dbf)

2. In "Choose a Destination" dialog, choose "MySQL";

- Input the server name (default: localhost), port (default: 3306), username, password.
- MySQL supporting some different Storage Engines, please click here to get more information about MySQL Storage Engine.
- Choose a character-set, e.g.: UTF-8.
- Press "Refresh" button to list all MySQL databases automation, you can choose an existing database or enter a new database name, this toolkit automatically create the new database during the migration process.
- MySQL

3. In "Select source Tables(s) & View(s)" dialog;

- Select the tables/views which will be migrated.
- Select Tables&Views
- Click "..." to set the table options or remap the table structure.
- Transform
- You can set the data transfer method (Overwrite Table/Empty Data/Append Data/Skip Table) or filter the data before transferring.
- Choose "Field Mapping" option, you can redefine the fields in the destination table, e.g.: field name, data type, default value, comment and also.

4. In "Execution" Dialog;

- Click "Submit" to begin the migration, this toolkit will help you quickly migrate data from Foxpro to MySQL without intervention.
- Execute
- Click "Browse Log" to visit the full migration log.
- Click "Save as job" to save the migration settings to a job file, so you can "Load Job" to quickly reload the migration job in the future or run the migration job via command-prompt. Run "esf-cmd --help" in command-prompt to get the full command parameters.

Take a look here for the source:

https://www.dbsofts.com/articles/foxpro_to_mysql/

If the above link no longer works use this link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20201125111036/https://www.dbsofts.com/articles/foxpro_to_mysql/